# Strange Memory leak

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have been working with iPhone application in which i am using sqlite database. I have checked memory leak in iPad,iPhone 4 and there is no memory leaks. But same code show memory leak in iPhone-3GS. Please take a look at below scree-shot and i think there is no leak than after instruments showing me leaks. Please do advice me.

Thanks in Advance.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its actually not that strange, see how you allocate memory for both `Query` and `Query1` via `[[NSArray alloc] init`. But then, you overwrite the pointer of them by calling `[database executeQuery:]`, so the allocated memory is leaked.

It looks like you don't really need the array allocation anyway, so you can simply remove that line. However, that the `[Query release]` and `[Query1 release]` doesn't crash the app (or at least at some later point), indicates that `[database executeQuery:]` return retained memory and thus delegates its ownership to the caller, which is discouraged by the memory guidelines. You should return an autoreleased object from  `executeQuery:`  and because you never use the returned value, you can simply reduce the method down to:

```
[self databaseOpen];
[database executeQuery:@"Delete from ActivityList"];
[database executeQuery:@"Select* from ActivityList"];
```

Comment: Yep you right. Than after it should also leaks in iPhone 4 and iPad also but it is not showing any memory leaks except in iPhone-3GS that's make me confuse.

Comment: @Nit I'm not quite sure why it doesn't show the leak on the iPhone 4, but keep in mind that Instruments leak detection is very conservative. It won't show leaks if it isn't 100% sure that it is leak, so chances are that the leak is treated as false/positive on the iPhone 4.

Comment: I am also thinking same and i have also got memory leak issue with UIImagePicker and it's also strange but i got solution for that. Now, I am confuse about Xcode development environment. It's almost 10th time that i am getting stuck because of Framework or apple development tools( I think apple development tools have more bugs than any of my application).

Answer (score 3):

The problem is this:

```
NSArray *Query = [[NSArray alloc] init];
// later:
Query = [database executeQuery:str];
```

Thusly, you allocate an NSArray, then reuse its pointer, so you loose the reference to the firstly allocated object. You don't need to do

```
NSArray *Query = [[NSArray alloc] init];
```

as the `executeQuery:` method returns an initialized array.

The same holds to Query1 as well (you're also allocating it erronously).

(By the way, are you using my SQLHelper library? If so, you must *not* release the array returned by the query; it's autoreleased and will crash upon overreleasing)

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're allocating `NSArray` for `Query` and `Query1` but never use them, you immediately change the pointer to something else which is your `[xxxx executeQuery:xxx]`.
Change them to these and it should be fine.

```
NSArray* Query = [database executeQuery:str];
NSArray* Query1 = [database executeQuery:str1];
```